# Regular expression troubles, escaped quotes

Tags: java, regex, unix, command-line

Basically, I'm being passed a string and I need to tokenise it in much the same manner as command line options are tokenised by a *nix shell

Say I have the following string

```
"Hello\" World" "Hello Universe" Hi
```

How could I turn it into a 3 element list

- Hello" World
- Hello Universe
- Hi

The following is my first attempt, but it's got a number of problems

- It leaves the quote characters
- It doesn't catch the escaped quote

Code:

```
public void test() {
    String str = "\"Hello\\\" World\" \"Hello Universe\" Hi";
    List<String> list = split(str);
}

public static List<String> split(String str) {
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(
        "\"[^\"]*\"" + /* double quoted token*/
        "|'[^']*'" + /*single quoted token*/
        "|[A-Za-z']+" /*everything else*/
    );

    List<String> opts = new ArrayList<String>();
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(str).useDelimiter(pattern);

    String token;
    while ((token = scanner.findInLine(pattern)) != null) {
        opts.add(token);
    }
    return opts;
}
```

So the incorrect output of the following code is

- "Hello\"
- World
- " "
- Hello
- Universe
- Hi

**EDIT** I'm totally open to a non regex solution.  It's just the first solution that came to mind

Comment: I would probably approach it like a CSV file instead of using regular expressions.  Essentially what you have is a space-delimited file where the "tokens" can be enclosed in quotes.

Comment: do you use only `"` and `'` to delimit tokens?

Comment: @Paul W, interesting, I'll look into that

Comment: @MarcoS, it's a space delimited string, unless the space is enclosed in " or '

Comment: I think you should build a small parser. Just regex will not do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you decide you want to forego regex, and do parsing instead, there are a couple of options.  If you are willing to have just a double quote or a single quote (but not both) as your quote, then you can use StreamTokenizer to solve this easily:

```
public static List<String> tokenize(String s) throws IOException {
    List<String> opts = new ArrayList<String>();
    StreamTokenizer st = new StreamTokenizer(new StringReader(s));
    st.quoteChar('\"');
    while (st.nextToken() != StreamTokenizer.TT_EOF) {
        opts.add(st.sval);
    }

    return opts;
}
```

If you must support both quotes, here is a naive implementation that should work (caveat that a string like '"blah \" blah"blah' will yield something like 'blah " blahblah'. If that isn't OK, you will need to make some changes):

```
   public static List<String> splitSSV(String in) throws IOException {
        ArrayList<String> out = new ArrayList<String>();

        StringReader r = new StringReader(in);
        StringBuilder b = new StringBuilder();
        int inQuote = -1;
        boolean escape = false;
        int c;
        // read each character
        while ((c = r.read()) != -1) {
            if (escape) {  // if the previous char is escape, add the current char
                b.append((char)c);
                escape = false;
                continue;
            }
            switch (c) {
            case '\\':   // deal with escape char
                escape = true;
                break;
            case '\"':
            case '\'':  // deal with quote chars
                if (c == '\"' || c == '\'') {
                    if (inQuote == -1) {  // not in a quote
                        inQuote = c;  // now we are
                    } else {
                        inQuote = -1;  // we were in a quote and now we aren't
                    }
                }
                break;
            case ' ':
                if (inQuote == -1) {  // if we aren't in a quote, then add token to list
                    out.add(b.toString());
                    b.setLength(0);
                } else {
                    b.append((char)c); // else append space to current token
                }
                break;
            default:
                b.append((char)c);  // append all other chars to current token
            }
        }
        if (b.length() > 0) {
            out.add(b.toString()); // add final token to list
        }
        return out;
    }
```

Comment: +1 for taking the time to write it. -1 for writing unreadable code.

Comment: @Daniel Hilgarth -- fair enough.  I added some comments but it still is probably not super readable.

Comment: I like the StreamTokenizer approach as i can mandate double quotes and not single quotes.  I'll give this a try

Comment: Very elaborated, maybe slightly unnecessary since you are better using reg ex for this type of problems, but +1 anyway.

Answer (score 2):

I'm pretty sure you can't do this by just tokenising on a regex.  If you need to deal with nested and escaped delimiters, you need to write a parser. See e.g. http://kore-nordmann.de/blog/do_NOT_parse_using_regexp.html

There will be open source parsers which can do what you want, although I don't know any.  You should also check out the StreamTokenizer class.

Answer (score 2):

To recap, you want to split on whitespace, except when surrounded by double quotes, which are not preceded by a backslash.

### Step 1: tokenize the input: `/([ \t]+)|(\\")|(")|([^ \t"]+)/`

This gives you a sequence of SPACE, ESCAPED_QUOTE, QUOTE and TEXT tokens.

### Step 2: build a finite state machine matching and reacting to the tokens:

#### State: START

- SPACE -> return empty string
- ESCAPED_QUOTE -> Error (?)
- QUOTE -> State := WITHIN_QUOTES
- TEXT -> return text

#### State: WITHIN_QUOTES

- SPACE -> add value to accumulator
- ESCAPED_QUOTE -> add quote to accumulator
- QUOTE -> return and clear accumulator; State := START
- TEXT -> add text to accumulator

### Step 3: Profit!!

Comment: that's pretty much it.  The only wrinkle is that i may need to deal with escaped backslashes as well (though I may get away with making it a requirement that backslashed can't be escaped)

Comment: @Glen: just enhance the state machine then. It's only a matter of adding a new token and deciding - for each state - what should happen if the token is encountered.

Answer (score 1):

I think if you use pattern like this:

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\".*?(?<!\\\\)\"|'.*?(?<!\\\\)'|[A-Za-z']+");
```

Then it will give you desired output. When I ran with your input data I got this list:

```
["Hello\" World", "Hello Universe", Hi]
```

I used `[A-Za-z']+` from your own question but shouldn't it be just : `[A-Za-z]+`

#### EDIT

Change your `opts.add(token);` line to:

```
opts.add(token.replaceAll("^\"|\"$|^'|'$", ""));
```

Comment: That preserves the double quotes, I need it to remove the quotes

Comment: @Glen, For that change your `opts.add(token);` line to: `opts.add(token.replaceAll("^\"|\"$|^'|'$", ""));` or see **EDIT** section above.

Answer (score 0):

The first thing you need to do is stop thinking of the job in terms of `split()`.  `split()` is meant for breaking down simple strings like `this/that/the other`, where `/` is always a delimiter.  But you're trying to split on whitespace, *unless* the whitespace is within quotes, *except* if the quotes are escaped with backslashes (and if backslashes escape quotes, they probably escape other things, like other backslashes).

With all those exceptions-to-exceptions, it's just not possible to create a regex to match all possible delimiters, not even with fancy gimmicks like lookarounds, conditionals, reluctant and possessive quantifiers.  What you want to do is match the *tokens*, not the delimiters.

In the following code, a token that's enclosed in double-quotes or single-quotes may contain whitespace as well as the quote character if it's preceded by a backslash.  Everything except the enclosing quotes is captured in group #1 (for double-quoted tokens) or group #2 (single-quoted).  Any character may be escaped with a backslash, even in non-quoted tokens; the "escaping" backslashes are removed in a separate step.

```
public static void test()
{
  String str = "\"Hello\\\" World\" 'Hello Universe' Hi";
  List<String> commands = parseCommands(str);
  for (String s : commands)
  {
    System.out.println(s);
  }
}

public static List<String> parseCommands(String s)
{
  String rgx = "\"((?:[^\"\\\\]++|\\\\.)*+)\""  // double-quoted
             + "|'((?:[^'\\\\]++|\\\\.)*+)'"    // single-quoted
             + "|\\S+";                         // not quoted
  Pattern p = Pattern.compile(rgx);
  Matcher m = p.matcher(s);
  List<String> commands = new ArrayList<String>();
  while (m.find())
  {
    String cmd = m.start(1) != -1 ? m.group(1) // strip double-quotes
               : m.start(2) != -1 ? m.group(2) // strip single-quotes
               : m.group();
    cmd = cmd.replaceAll("\\\\(.)", "$1");  // remove escape characters
    commands.add(cmd);
  }
  return commands;
}
```

output:

```
Hello" World
Hello Universe
Hi
```

This is about as simple as it gets for a regex-based solution--and it doesn't really deal with malformed input, like unbalanced quotes.  If you're not fluent in regexes, you might be better off with a purely hand-coded solution or, even better, a dedicated command-line interpreter (CLI) library.