# Separate out unix statements separated by `(, ), ||, &&, |`

Tags: algorithm, parsing, language-agnostic

I have a string with several unix statements, joined with `(, ), ||, &&, |`. I want to separate them out into arrays (nested?) in the order they would be evaluated in a unix command line. I preferably want them in a prefix notation, but anything would do.

like

```
a --foo "b|a||r" && a -b || (a || a) | c | d
```

should become

```
["|", ["|", ["||", ["&&", "a --foo \"b|a||r\"", "a -b"], ["||", "a", "a"]], "c"], "d"]
```

(Really tried to give an example that involves all possibilities.

How should I approach this?

I can understand code in most of the popular high level (OOP) languages (ruby, python, etc), or even a pseudocode would help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you think about it, the task is not different from parsing a mathematical expression, e.g. `a * (b + c) / d` ==> `[/, [*, a, [+, b, c]], d]` . Thus, you can use the same tools:

You need is an **infix parser**.

(*Infix*, because your operators are *between* the operands: e.g. `a && b`)

Browse over the [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operator-precedence_parser) for a bit of theoretical background, then grab an existing parser for the language you would like to use and define the operators as well as their precedence.

Comment: I don't think that would be able to parse `cat "a&&b" | echo` properly?

Comment: @user1527166: That should be taken care of in the *tokenizing* step, i.e. when you split your string into simple units: Stuff between `"` should be fully tokenized as a string.

Comment: Hmm, one more thing before I try that, can it handle `cat "a\"b\""`? (ie, \" will escape a quote, not ending the string).

Comment: @user1527166: That depends on how your implement your tokenizer. Here is an example in Java that respects escaped double quotes: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6030400/regular-expression-troubles-escaped-quotes